# How to split XML having nested loops in Talend

Tags: xml, talend

In the below XML there is a nested loops. Bit struggling to split them into one row per MAV.CAMS.

Expected Output:

First MAV.CAMS should split

Second MMB should be split

Third MMR should be split

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<REQUEST>
<REQUEST_TYPE>NEW</REQUEST_TYPE>
<MOD>
<MOD.CAMS>
<MOD_CODE>ABCD1004</MOD_CODE>
<MAV>
<MAV.CAMS>
<MOD_CODE>ABCD1004</MOD_CODE>
<MAP>
<MAP.CAMS>
<MAP_CODE>ABCD1004_201</MAP_CODE>
<MAB>
<MAB.CAMS>
<AST_CODE>CWRK</AST_CODE>
<MAB_PERC>100</MAB_PERC>
</MAB.CAMS>
<MAB.CAMS>
<AST_CODE>EX</AST_CODE>
<MAB_PERC>200</MAB_PERC>
</MAB.CAMS>          
</MAB>
</MAP.CAMS>
</MAP>
<MMR>
<MMR.CAMS>
<MOD_CODE>ABCD1004</MOD_CODE>
<REX_CODE>PRE</REX_CODE>
<MMB>
<MMB.CAMS>       
<MMB_SEQ>1</MMB_SEQ>
<FMC_CODE>AER298</FMC_CODE>
</MMB.CAMS>
<MMB.CAMS>       
<MMB_SEQ>2</MMB_SEQ>
<FMC_CODE>AER299</FMC_CODE>
</MMB.CAMS>
</MMB>       
</MMR.CAMS>
<MMR.CAMS>
<MOD_CODE>ABCD1004</MOD_CODE>
<REX_CODE>CO</REX_CODE>
<MMR_DESC/>
<MMB>
<MMB.CAMS>       
<MMB_SEQ>1</MMB_SEQ>
<FMC_CODE>AER301</FMC_CODE>
</MMB.CAMS>
<MMB.CAMS>       
<MMB_SEQ>2</MMB_SEQ>
<FMC_CODE>AER445</FMC_CODE>
</MMB.CAMS>
</MMB>       
</MMR.CAMS>  
</MMR>
</MAV.CAMS>  
<MAV.CAMS>
<MOD_CODE>ABCD1004</MOD_CODE>
<MAP>
<MAP.CAMS>
<MAP_CODE>ABCD1004_201</MAP_CODE>
<MAB>
<MAB.CAMS>
<AST_CODE>CWRK</AST_CODE>
<MAB_PERC>200</MAB_PERC>
</MAB.CAMS>
<MAB.CAMS>
<AST_CODE>EX</AST_CODE>
<MAB_PERC>500</MAB_PERC>
</MAB.CAMS>          
</MAB>
</MAP.CAMS>
</MAP>
<MMR>
<MMR.CAMS>
<MOD_CODE>ABCD1004</MOD_CODE>
<REX_CODE>PRE</REX_CODE>
<MMB>
<MMB.CAMS>       
<MMB_SEQ>1</MMB_SEQ>
<FMC_CODE>AER298</FMC_CODE>
</MMB.CAMS>
<MMB.CAMS>       
<MMB_SEQ>2</MMB_SEQ>
<FMC_CODE>AER299</FMC_CODE>
</MMB.CAMS>
</MMB>       
</MMR.CAMS>
<MMR.CAMS>
<MOD_CODE>ABCD1004</MOD_CODE>
<REX_CODE>CO</REX_CODE>
<MMR_DESC/>
<MMB>
<MMB.CAMS>       
<MMB_SEQ>1</MMB_SEQ>
<FMC_CODE>AER301</FMC_CODE>
</MMB.CAMS>
<MMB.CAMS>       
<MMB_SEQ>2</MMB_SEQ>
<FMC_CODE>AER445</FMC_CODE>
</MMB.CAMS>
</MMB>       
</MMR.CAMS>  
</MMR>
</MAV.CAMS>
</MAV>
</MOD.CAMS>
</MOD>
</REQUEST>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I think you meant : MAV > MMR > MMB and not MAV> MMB>MMR.

If you want in your output 1 row per MAV.CAMS, you have to put the loop element on MAV.CAMS.
In your example file, you would have an output with 2 rows (2 MAV.CAMS)
But if you want all the details regarding nested elements, you should put your loop element at the deepest element (MMB.CAMS) . Then you would have on the output  8 rows (as there are 8 MMB.CAMS elements in the input).